# In a MongoDB index, what do the options "safe" and "force" mean?

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking at our Mongo (2.4.10) indexes, using collection.getIndexes(). I see options that aren't discussed in any doc I can find. Specifically, I see the options "safe" and "force". For example below:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "name" : "status_1",
    "key" : {
        "status" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "ns" : "db.mycoll",
    "force" : true,
    "background" : true
},
```

What do "force" and "safe" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The options you mention ("force" and "safe") are not valid index options for MongoDB 2.4.

They likely resulted from a developer accidentally ensuring an index including these as index options (perhaps having intended for those fields to be part of the index criteria?).

You can reproduce this outcome in the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.foo.ensureIndex({foo: true}, {force: true, safe: true})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}

> db.foo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "stack.foo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "foo" : true
        },
        "name" : "foo_true",
        "ns" : "stack.foo",
        "force" : true,
        "safe" : true
    }
]
>
```

Unknown index options will be ignored (at least as at MongoDB 3.0), so while this is confusing the impact is currently benign. Unfortunately the only way to remove the invalid options would be dropping & rebuilding the affected index(es) as there is no API for [changing an existing index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-an-index/).

It's possible that index option validation may be added in a future MongoDB release, but this should be noted as a compatibility change in the release notes. For example, MongoDB 2.6 has several [index changes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/#index-changes) including better field name validation and enforcement of index key length.

Comment: Were they valid options in previous versions of mongo?

Comment: @PaulBiggar "force" and "safe" aren't valid index options in any version of MongoDB as far as I'm aware. My history only covers 1.8+ so it's possible these may have had some historical use, but I think the field names suggest actions rather than options you would need to save in an index. The lack of validation of index options per the example I included is still true as at MongoDB 3.0.4.

Comment: `safe` is now invalid, and v3.7 will refuse to restore an index with `safe` set as a field in the specification.